# select only numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

У меня есть field текст, в нем есть информация примерно такие

```
sch hcbhsc hscbshcbc  `xxxxxxxx` sgxfag jdhajdh;

dchbdbc bdcbdh bchdbd  `xx/xx-xxxx/xx` svdhs sbjbsc

bdchbdc jncjdnc jbcjb  `xx/xx-xxxxx/xx`gcvsgc jcbjsb

dchjbd bhjcbdcb bdcbcd  `xx-xxxx/xx` shchscv hscbhsc

dhcbhd jdcbjdb jdcnjdcn  `xx-xxxxx/xx` shcvsch jbscjc
```

место х - ов только цифри, мне надо написат select и взят только эти цифри

Comment: Хитрый вопрос... Если я правильно понял - совет Вам запрашивать как есть и средствами языка программирования разбирать на числа. [Есть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186272.aspx), конечно, и в БД средства проверок типа, но не везде.Приходится [выкручиваться](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5064977/detect-if-value-is-number-in-mysql)

Comment: цифры всегда идут записаны в скобках `` ?

Comment: нет просто так без скобки

Comment: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=815  тут есть функция которая возращает все цифры со строки. Но да, захватит абсолютно все цифры ячейки..

Comment: А знаки препинания внутри строки цифр надо сохранять и одно ли число всегда в строке, т.е. можно ли вырезать всю строку с позиции первой встреченной цифры и до последней